# JAVA - REGEX : Don't replace string if it matches a pattern

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have a function to sanitized user input  `<script> alert('xss') </script>`. So, The output will be `&lt;script&gt; alert&#40;&#39;xss&#39;&#41; &lt;&#x2Fscript&gt;`

But when input user already sanitized in front-end side I will receive `&lt;` and the output will be converted to `&amp;lt;`

So my method will convert all `&` into a sanitized input. And my need is not to convert the `&` which is followed by `&amp; &lt; &gt; &#40; &#41; &#39; &quot; &#x2F`

Here is my function :

```
    public static String xssFilter(final String value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    String sanitized = value;
    // Simple characters
    sanitized = sanitized.replace("&", "&amp;");
    sanitized = sanitized.replace("<", "&lt;").replace(">", "&gt;");
    sanitized = sanitized.replace("(", "&#40;").replace(")", "&#41;");
    sanitized = sanitized.replace("'", "&#39;");
    sanitized = sanitized.replace("\"", "&quot;");
    sanitized = sanitized.replace("/", "&#x2F");
    
    
    // RegEx pattern
    sanitized = sanitized.replaceAll("eval\\((.*)\\)", "");
    sanitized = sanitized.replaceAll("[\\\"\\\'][\\s]*javascript:(.*)[\\\"\\\']", "\"\"");
    return sanitized;
}
```

Comment: In case there is need for 'sanitize' the string, the input is always the form '<string> code </string>'? 
What you can do is split the function in two, where in one you handle situation like the input like the example i gave, and the other detect if its already sanitized.

Comment: The general solution for this kind of encoding, also taking care of half- or self-sanitized strings, is to first **unsanitize** it and then **sanitize** it.

Comment: The direct answer to your question is that you want a negative lookahead `sanitized.replaceAll("&(?!(?:amp|lt|gt|#40|#41|#39|quot|#x2F);)")` but the actual answer is **"don't do that"**, for both semantic and security reasons: how do you know whether your user typed `&amp;` or `&`? Selective sanitisation for security is likely to end badly. The correct answer for your system as a whole to know that the data is, or is not, encoded, and to treat it appropriately. Do specify whether the client should sanitize data (and check that it did!). Do not use `innerHTML()` in your UI, for example.